# How to parse file with system characters?

Tags: python

I have file like below:

> ’”ЪNUL$13adc1e6-465e-11e1-a8f8-047d7b47de33“®188.254.116.66®188.254.116.67®188.254.116.68ЁРЈСЂРЅР°ЪNUL
> ed4bac9f1f1bf6812e76ef21a78fe9c0”ЪNUL$13b2fd14-465e-11e1-a8f8-047d7b47de33“®188.254.116.66®188.254.116.67®188.254.116.68°РљРѕРјРёСЃСЃРёСЏЪNUL
> 194bb53b6970bcc08ca743d2d238057f

(original can be downloaded [here](http://webvybory2012.ru/account/channels?station_id=65600))

How can I parse that (once downloaded) to extract:

> 13adc1e6-465e-11e1-a8f8-047d7b47de33
>
> 13b2fd14-465e-11e1-a8f8-047d7b47de33
>
> 188.254.116.66

? I am not sure how to look for this system characters.

Comment: What's a "system character"? Are you looking for [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html)?

Comment: I tried to download the original, but all I got was a Russian login page.

Comment: @Gabe, sorry for this. Please use login `abu@asdasd.ru` and pass `123456`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not think of "characters" in this case.  The file is in a binary format.

If you don't have a hold of the file format specification (which would be ideal), you should be looking at a hex dump of the file, not a text print of it like here.

For example `®` is very likely (but not certainly, because a text print like this is not accurate) a byte of value `A9`.  This will be apparent from the hex dump.

You can then scan for `'\xa9'` in the data byte string.